# How to update a part of a WPF custom style

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls, properties, styles

I have created a custom window control (inherited from Window), all is fine except the text of my status bar. I have added a new property to my control called "StatusText" and this text is shown inside a TextBlock in my control's style.

But when I change the StatusText property of my window the text doesn't change, it's not update. On another side, if I change the Title property of my window (which is an inherited property) the Title change correctly.

So maybe I have not correctly declared my StatusText property ? Or I need to explicitly ask for the TextBlock in my style to update ?

Thank for your help.

StatusText Property Declaration :

```
    private string m_StatusText;

    public string StatusText
    {
        get { return m_StatusText; }
        set { m_StatusText = value; }
    }
```

XAML Style for the status bar :

```
<!-- Status area -->
<Border Grid.Row="2" Style="{DynamicResource SFM_StatusAreaStyle}" CornerRadius="0, 0, 7, 7" BorderThickness="1, 1, 1, 0">
    <Grid Style="{DynamicResource SFM_TitleBarStyleReflect}">
          <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6, 0, 0, 2" Foreground="{DynamicResource B_TextColor}" 
                                Text="{Binding Path=StatusText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:SiluForm}, Mode=FindAncestor}}" />
    </Grid>
 </Border>
```

Comment: can you please post your code?  I'm assuming that you want to use databinding to accomplish the text change, but no one knows for sure what you're doing unless you post code / XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your class containing `StatusText` and then insert code of rasing `PropertyChanged` event in setter of `StatusText`:

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string m_StatusText;

    public string StatusText
    {
        get { return m_StatusText; }
        set 
        { 
             m_StatusText = value; 
             raiseOnPropertyChanged("StatusText");
        }
    }

   #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void raiseOnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Comment: Hi and thank for your answer, but I can't inherit INotifyPropertyChanged as my control already inherit the Window class. C# doesn't support multiple inheritance right ?

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is an interface, C# classes can inherit from multiple interfaces, as they specify what a class must contain without specifying exact functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface as Eugene answered above, you might also need to set `DataContext = this` in your custom window classes constructor. Then you shouldn't need the RelativeSource binding.

Unless you're using the DataContext of the custom window for other purposes.